# Multiprocessing using map

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocess

I have a list of strings and on every string I am doing some changes that you can see in `wordify()`. Now, to speed this up, I split up the list into sublists using `chunked()` (the number of sublists is the number of CPU cores - 1). That way I get lists that look like `[[,,],[,,],[,,],[,,]]` .

What I try to achieve:

I want to do `wordify()` on every of these sublists simultaneously, returning the sublists as separate lists. I want to wait until all processes finish and then join these sublists into one list. The approach below does not work.

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
from contextlib import closing

def readFiles():
    words = []
    with open("somefile.txt") as f:
        w = f.readlines()
    words = words + w 
    return words


def chunked(words, num_cpu):
    avg = len(words) / float(num_cpu)
    out = []
    last = 0.0    
    while last < len(words):
        out.append(words[int(last):int(last + avg)])
        last += avg    
    return out    


def wordify(chunk,wl):
    wl.append([chunk[word].split(",", 1)[0] for word in range(len(chunk))]) 
    return wl


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_cpu = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1
    words = readFiles()
    chunked = chunked(words, num_cpu)
    wordlist = []
    wordify(words, wordlist) # works
    with closing(Pool(processes = num_cpu)) as p:
        p.map(wordify, chunked, wordlist) # fails
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have write your code so that you're just passing a single function to `map`; it's not smart enough to know that your hoping it passes `wordlist` into the second argument of your function.

TBH partial function application is a bit clunky in Python, but you can use `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial
p.map(partial(wordify, wordlist), chunked)
```

Comment: First solution gives me:
`cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed`

Second solution works but it is slower than doing it singlethreaded:
`singlethreaded: 0.423000097275`, `multithreaded: 0.605999946594`

Comment: You shouldn't expect a speed boost unless the work being done is substantial.  Splitting a line by the first comma is little work, and it's almost certainly more time-consuming just to send the strings back and forth over interprocess pipes.  It's not really that the latter is notably expensive, it's more that what you're _doing_ with the strings is very cheap.

Comment: The amount of data this will be done to will increase substantially. Is there a more efficient way to do this as I absolutely do not see any need to send strings between processes while the sublists are being modified. Stuff only should be sent back and forth when rejoining the sublists.

Comment: What I'm saying has nothing to do with the amount of data.  It's solely about the expense of interprocess communication versus the expense of "useful work" done.  _Everything_ you pass as an argument is pickled (serialized into a string format) and sent over an interprocess pipe, and likewise for _everything_ returned by a worker process.  The processes do not share memory - all communication of all values between processes occurs by sending pickle strings over pipes.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have a similar use case where I use a lot of regex which should be heavier on CPU. I'll see if it is more effective there.

Comment: i forgot that lambda doesn't work, i'll remove that from the answer

Comment: If you are looking for a multi-argument `map` and the ability to serialize `lambda` and most other python objects, you might want to check out the fork of `multiprocessing` in `pathos.multiprocessing`. (shameless plug - I'm the author)